# Where does GCM data to be pushed get stored?

Tags: android, mysql, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

In GCM, there are three main components

1. GCM server
2. third party app server
3. client (mobile)

Which one of them stores the data that is to be pushed?
For example, if a mobile1 has to communicate with a mobile2 and it wants to send a message "HI" and an image, then where does this two pieces of data get stored, on the app server, or on the GCM server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found out a solution the flow is like from

app server to ccs to gcm

Answer (score 0):

You are not expected to send pushes from one mobile to another. You need the data to get through a server (given your tags, possibly an XMPP server or anything else).
It means that data get indeed store on your own server not GCM.

Not that GCM does not do image transfert. You should only transfert notification about the fact that an image is available somewhere to download.

Comment: thankyou for fast relpy and sir 1) which server preference is better xmpp/something else like is php mysql via phpmyadmin suitable for such large data to be stored?2)Also my data gets stored temporary on the app server till the data is transferred to gcm is that right (after push the data is deleted from my server??)Sorry but one more que does the data then get stored on the mobile device like whatsapp or somewhere else

Comment: You likely need both an XMPP server and a more general backend doing web.

Comment: so is php +mysql enough or something in addition?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. PHP + MySQL are not intended for building real time messaging apps. XMPP is good for that.

Comment: thankyou sir is thiis the correct implementation   http://www.grokkingandroid.com/xmpp-server-google-cloud-messaging/ and this is the github  https://github.com/writtmeyer/gcm_server

Comment: ok tanks a ton sir for your valuable time,please do tell me about that grokingandroid tutorial is that fully implemented?